# QtCore/QtGlobal: No such file or directory

Tags: qt

I am trying to build two libraries: one static one shared. The problem is with the static library. I have the following folders:

```
src/
  db/
    dbal.h
    dbal.pro
  dll/
    Distribution.h
    dll.pro
  project.pro
```

*db is static and dll is shared*

**Distribution.h**:

```
#ifndef DISTRIBUTION_H_
#define DISTRIBUTION_H_

#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>

#if defined(BUILDING_DLL)
#define DLL_FUNCTION Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define DLL_FUNCTION Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif /* DISTRIBUTION_H_ */
```

Now here is the file inside db/ that includes `Distribution.h`

**dbal.h**

```
#ifndef DBAL_H_
#define DBAL_H_

#include "Distribution.h"

...

#endif
```

**db.pro**:

```
TARGET = db
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG = staticlib c++11

QT += core

INCLUDEPATH += ../dll

HEADERS += dbal.h
HEADERS += dbal_sqlite.h

SOURCES += dbal.cpp
SOURCES += dbal_sqlite.cpp

######################################################################
# Build to custom directories
######################################################################

DESTDIR = ../../build/debug/db

OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.qrc
UI_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.ui
```

When I run make in the db/ folder I get the following error: QtCore/QtGlobal: No such file or directory. It also appears that there are missing -I commands.

Here is my log:

```
make all 
cd src/db/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /mnt/record/_dev/linux/projects/cdt/wasp/src/db/db.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile all
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/record/_dev/linux/projects/cdt/wasp/src/db'
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x  -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I../dll -o ../../build/debug/db/.obj/dbal.o dbal.cpp
In file included from dbal.h:9:0,
                 from dbal.cpp:3:
../dll/Distribution.h:4:27: fatal error: QtCore/QtGlobal: No such file or directory
 #include <QtCore/QtGlobal>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: What is your Qt version?

Comment: Did you try `#include <QtGlobal>`?

Comment: Yeaup, no workie. The QtCore/QtGlobal include works when I run the makefile inside dll/ but it does not work when I get to the makefile in db/

Comment: I don't normally compile in g++ but shouldn't your -I paths include the Qt root include path? qt5/mkspecs does not contain Qt headers

Comment: Yeah, it should. Do you think it's because I trying to compile a static library that qmake does not include the Qt include paths?

Comment: You'd need the same paths whether or not you're compiling static or shared, but there might be something with `configure` that is messed up possibly specifically for a static configuration.

Comment: Do shared lib projects compile fine with the same Qt?

Comment: I have totally simplified my project to a simple shared library project and I have the same issue. Just can't get Qt to use the Qt library with CONFIG += lib

Comment: @iminyourbrain If you make an answer containing your comment observation that the -l was missing necessary includes, along with the answer that I posted, I will gladly up-vote it and accept it as the best answer.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help along at least part of the way of self discovery :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the log:

> g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x  -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I../dll -o ../../build/debug/db/.obj/dbal.o dbal.cpp

shows the includes the paths that are provided to g++ and doesn't include a path to `QtCore/QtGlobal`.

The solution is that the .pro file needs

`CONFIG = staticlib c++11`

to be changed to:

`CONFIG += staticlib c++11`

Specifically, the `CONFIG = ...` line has *removed* the `qt` element from the configuration, thus your project wasn't including nor linking Qt files.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the following line:

```
CONFIG = staticlib c++11
```

The fix is changing it to:

```
CONFIG += staticlib c++11
```

Apparently without the += operator I was overriding necessary Qt default config variable values.